# vue 3 and option api reactive data non reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 <script>
export default {
data(){
return {

charts : [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "pie",
        style: {
          width: "73.189%",
          height: "347.969px",
        },
        questions: 3,
        chart_data: [
          {
            order_id: 3,
            value: "HTC Vive Pro",
            count: 1,
          },
          {
            order_id: 3,
            value: "Oculus Go",
            count: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      // ... other chart objects
    ]}
}
}
   </script>
```

I have this reactive array
and I  when I change it inside a method by  doing this:

```
this.charts[0].chart_data=[
          {
            order_id: 3,
            value: "jdezjkd",
            count: 8,
          },
          {
            order_id: 3,
            value: "loremjebd",
            count: 8,
          },
        ]
```

the reactive charts property change but the component doesn't renderer and I don't understand why
could someone help me please?

Comment: it should be `charts : [` not `charts = [`

Comment: Boussadjra Brahim thanks you,  but this is not  the real  problem it  is a mistake I have done while changing the code for StackOverflow I don't have this mistake in the real code

Comment: Please try the classic debugging tool - `{{ charts[0].chart_data }}` in template to show the current value. Does it change in root component? In child component?

Comment: Can you please show how `charts` is being used?  As in show some template code.  Are you using any third party chart library? Please always include this kind of info if you are, as it's very important for others to gain a full and clear picture of what's happening.